# Getting read-ops/sec in YugabyteDB node through the CLI

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I log in my VM using ssh. I can't connect to VM's IP:7000 directly using the browser. How can I get read ops/sec and write ops/sec etc by bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this in Python (with pandas installed):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
master='http://localhost:7000'
# install pandas module with:
#    python -m pip install pandas
import pandas
from datetime import datetime
tablet_servers=(pandas.read_html(master+'/tablet-servers')[0])
tablet_servers['Server'].replace(to_replace="(:[0-9]+)?( [0-9a-f]*)?$"
 , value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
print(tablet_servers[['Server','Read ops/sec','Write ops/sec']])
```

But you can also probably tunnel the 7000 port through `ssh (-L 7000:localhost:7000)` to get it from your browser.